# JQuery Colorbox: Is it possible to show two or more colorbox side by side with individual close button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I need to show two to four colorbox side by side on onClick event. I'm a novice to JQuery. Is there already built in something or is there any existing website that is using this? I'm not sure about the possibility whether it is possible or not. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you really need 2-4 colorbox next to each other. You can easily have Colorbox display multiple pieces of content in one Colorbox. If you can provide an example of what you are trying to do perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with colorbox.  You might want to try the jQuery UI modal dialog.